# Why do I need to cast the value of the Rx object on initialization?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, static-typing

Consider this code:

```
Rx<Widget> rxwidget = const Text("test").obs;
rxwidget.value = Container();
```

This will throw the following error on runtime

```
Expected a value of type 'Text', but got one of type 'Container'
```

This seems very illogical to me because the variable only requires it to be a `Widget` which both are. It somehow restricts the type to the first value it gets.
But if I write it like this:

```
Rx<Widget> rxwidget = (const Text("test") as Widget).obs;
rxwidget.value = Container();
```

It works fine, but the IDE (Android Studio) actually complains that the cast is unnecessary.
Note, removing the `const` keyword doesn't help.

Another example

```
Rx<String?> test = null.obs;
test.value = "test";
```

giving

```
Expected a value of type 'Null', but got one of type 'String'
```

I'm pretty sure it used to work, so I suspect it's a recent change in flutter.

Is this maybe an error in flutter/dart? Or why is this?

version info:

```
Flutter 2.10.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7e9793dee1 (2 weeks ago) • 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
Engine • revision bd539267b4
Tools • Dart 2.16.1 • DevTools 2.9.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of

```dart
Rx<T> get obs => Rx<T>(this);
```

So `(const Text("test")).obs` has type `Rx<Text>` -> wrong

Solution

```
final rxwidget = Rx<Widget>(const Text("test"));
```

Comment: I guess you are right. but somehow I seem to remember it used to work the way I wrote it just fine. Maybe it's a change in GetX or something or I just remember wrongly.